# Does GWT's JSR 303 validation work with AutoBeans?

Tags: java, validation, gwt, autobean

The newest release of GWT has support for [JSR 303 Bean Validation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation).

I've hunted around, and I yet to find any mention of whether or not this works with AutoBeans.

Any ideas?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I am inclined to say yes as RequestFactory is supposed to work with AutoBean and JSR 303 Bean validation.